# Java Encoding for "GB2312" CHARACTER ® replacing with question mark(?)

Tags: java

I'm trying to get encoded value using `GB2312` characterset but I'm getting '? 'instead of '®'

Below is my sample code:

```
new String("Test ®".getBytes("GB2312"));
```

but I'm getting Test ? instead of Test ®.

Does any one faced this issue?

Java version- `JDK6`

Platform: `Window 7`

I'm not aware of Chinese character encoding so need suggestion.

Comment: Probably ® cannot be encoded in GB2312, so it is converted to `?`. See the result of `Charset.forName("GB2312").newEncoder().canEncode("®")`

Comment: Thanks Carlos, So is this expected behavior for any other characterset encoding?

Comment: not really, it is a possible behavior, see my answer

Answer (score 0):

For better understanding, the statement divided in two parts:

```
byte[] bytes = "Test ®".getBytes("GB2312");  // bytes, encoding the string to GB2312
new String(bytes);  // back to string, using default encoding
```

Probably `®` is not a valid GB2312 character, so it is converted to `?`. See the result of

```
Charset.forName("GB2312").newEncoder().canEncode("®")
```

Based on [documentation of `getBytes`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#getBytes-java.lang.String-):

> The behavior of this method when this string cannot be encoded in the given charset is unspecified. The CharsetEncoder class should be used when more control over the encoding process is required.

which also suggest using [`CharsetEncoder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/charset/CharsetEncoder.html).